# Many to many check if one list contains elements of another

Tags: java, jsp

I have two entities: **Shop** and **Transport** with many to many relation.
And I have page for editing Shop entity where user can see list of shop's transports like checkboxes.

To show user all transports I'm using for each by all transports:

```
<c:forEach items="${transports}" var="transport">
    <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" value="${transport.id}"> ${transport.name}
        </label>
    </div>
</c:forEach>
```

Also on this page I have an object **Shop** and can get list of shop's transports. The problem is I want to mark as checked shop's transport when I show list of all transports.
So user will be able to see which transports belong to shop and which do not.

Can't figure out how to check it in my loop. Thanks in advance.

**EDITED**

```
public boolean hasTransport(Transport transport, Integer id) {
        boolean result = false;
        for (Shop shop : transport.getShops()) {
            if (shop.getId().equals(id)) {
                result = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

And check it on jsp page:

```
<c:forEach items="${transports}" var="transport">
<div class="checkbox">
    <label>
        <c:choose>
            <c:when test="${shop.hasTransport(transport, shop.id)}">
                <input type="checkbox" checked name="transportsId" value="${transport.id}"> ${transport.name}
            </c:when>
            <c:otherwise>
                <input type="checkbox" name="transportsId" value="${transport.id}"> ${transport.name}
            </c:otherwise>
        </c:choose>
    </label>
</div>
</c:forEach>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a method to Shop:

public class Shop{

```
......


private Set<Transport> transports;


public boolean hasTransport(Transport transport){
    //check if Set contains specified transport
    //implement equals/hasCode or iterate and check the Ids 

}

.....
```

}

If your application is Servlet Spec 3 compliant you can call it from EL:

```
<c:forEach items="${transports}" var="transport">
    <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" value="${transport.id}" checked="${shop.hasTransport(transport)}"/> ${transport.name}
        </label>
    </div>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, could you please see my edited question above, I added helper method as you advised and also added check on the jsp page, is it okay? Or maybe is there better way (i mean implementation in helper method)

Answer (score 0):

One straightforward solution would be:

1) Implement a checker method inside Transport class which would check if a given Transport has a relation with a given Shop (Transport#isRelatedWith(Shop):boolean)

2) Create a tag (could be either a Java implementation or a JSP) which would use the checker method to set status of checkboxes

Another solution (not recommended) would be to implement this logic right in place, using JSP so-called scriptlets <% code-goes-here %>